# What is the intuition behind using the fixed point of this function to show the convergence of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, contest-math, intuition

In https://ssmr.ro/gazeta/gma/2021/gma3-4-2021-continut.pdf on page 33 we have the solution of a problem from a contest for university students. I will write here the statement and the solution of the problem to keep my post self contained:

**Problem.** Let $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be the sequence defined by $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{n}{1+x_n}$ for all $n\ge 1$. Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (x_n-\sqrt{n})$.

**Solution.** For a positive integer $n\ge 1$, let $a_n=\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}-1}{2}$ be the unique fixed point of the function $f_n : (0, \infty)\to (0, \infty)$, $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{1+x}$. The following statement can be obtained by induction:
$$a_{n-1}<x_n<a_n, \forall n \ge 5.$$
Then we have $$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4n-3}-1}{2}<x_n-\sqrt{n}<-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}-2\sqrt{n}}{2}, \forall n\ge5,$$ so the Squeeze Theorem implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (x_n-\sqrt{n})=-\frac{1}{2}.$

I don't understand the motivation behind this solution. I mean all right, I've seen problems where we look at the fixed point of the (sequence of) function(s) that defines/define our sequence, but I don't really understand why we would do this here. I suppose that the motivation is that nice inequality $a_{n-1}<x_n<a_n$ for $n\ge 5$, but I don't understand why we would know that such a thing would occur (I get that it can be proved by induction, but how would you come up with it? What is the intuition or the more general result here?).

EDIT: As requested in the comments, I will add my thoughts on the problem even though I am only interested in understanding the particular solution from above. I have only thought about looking at the monotonicity of $x_n$. I saw that $x_2=\frac{1}{2}$, $x_3=\frac{4}{3}$, $x_4=\frac{9}{7}$, $x_5=\frac{35}{16}$, so it looks as if from $n=4$ it is increasing. But I don't see how I could reasonably prove this. I tried an induction proof, but it didn't really work.

Comment: That specific induction inequality isn't needed (though it is helpful). Can you show what you've tried for this problem.

Comment: @CalvinLin well, I was mostly helpless when it came to solving it, but I will add my thoughts on the problem in my OP. I mostly wanted to understand this official solution because it seems weird to me and I suspect that there are some fixed point results that motivate this approach (I believe this simply because nowhere does the solution make use of the fact that $a_n$ is the unique fixed point of the function $f_n$; it just provides us with the bound, but why would we think about this? Why would we expect this to provide us a bound in the first place?)

Comment: $x _n \approx $ the fixed point of $ f(x) = \frac{n}{1+x}$ shouldn't be too surprising. That's essentially what we (unrigorously) do to determine a limit after assuming/proving a limit exists especially for cases where $f(x)$ doesn't depend on $n$. With this wishful thinking/assumption, we get that $\lim x_n - \sqrt{n} = - 1/2$ and it remains to establish that.

Comment: @CalvinLin I see, so basically in general we may hope that $x_n\approx$ the fixed point of the function that defines the sequence based on the way we generally find the limit of a recurrent sequence and in some cases this hope turns out to be actually true, right? If I understand correctly this is the intuition behind the solution.

Comment: Essentially yes, especially for functions where $f'$ is negative because that means it "helps" correct the error. Normally (EG for functions not depending on $n$), It would be nice if $ |f'|$ is small so that means that we get more accurate. Notice that's not the case here, we have $ -1 \approx < f' $ which is needed to push $x_n$ along the intervals $[a_{n-1}, a_n]$ while reducing the error (intervals get smaller).

Comment: @CalvinLin thank you very much, you really helped me out! The solution looked artificial to me, but now I really get it and it's a nice idea.

Comment: I think that the first motivation is to obtain a sequence whose general term can be expressed as a function of n. Indeed if we search for $a_n$ such that $a_n = f_n (a_n)$, we will no longer have a sequence of the form $u_{n + 1} = f_n (u_n)$. Then the fact that it is framing of $ x_n $ is a kind of happy coincidence.